# Get request JSON in postman test

Tags: json, api, testing, postman

The request body of my postman test is JSON data:

```
{
    "key_outer": {
         "key_inner: "value"
    }
}
```

In the Postman test, I am trying to compare part of the response (also JSON) with part of the request. I can get the response with

```
var response = pm.response.json();
```

and I can access any object e.g. with `response.key_outer.key_inner`. But when I try the same with the request, it does not work:

```
var response = pm.response.json().key_outer.key_inner;  // TypeError: pm.request.json is not a function
var response = pm.response.json.key_outer.key_inner;  // TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'key_outer')
var response = pm.response.body.key_outer.key_inner;  // TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'key_inner')
var response = pm.response.body.json().key_outer.key_inner;  // TypeError: pm.request.json is not a function
var response = pm.response.body.json.key_outer.key_inner;  // TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'key_outer')
var response = pm.response.body.toJSON().key_outer.key_inner;  // TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'key_inner')
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `pm.request` at the point at which you are trying to invoke `.json` on it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running `console.log(pm.request.body)` showed that it is a raw string, so

```
var request = JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw);
```

gave the expected result.